# How do I solve this spec loader error in apache isis

Tags: isis

I am using the income platform as a test platform. I have added an entity in a separate module Provider. Provider has a reference to itself via a parent property. I want to ensure that I can use autocomplete or be able to select a provider from a list when filling the parent field.
Whenever I add the Autocomplete option in the @DomainObject annotation and reference the ProviderRepository, I am getting a build error as below.

```
    [DEBUG] Meta model invalid
org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.specloader.validator.MetaModelInvalidException: 1: @DomainObject annotation on domainapp.modules.provider.dom.Provider specifies unknown repository 'd
omainapp.modules.provider.dom.ProviderRepository'

        at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.specloader.validator.ValidationFailures.assertNone(ValidationFailures.java:51)
        at org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.specloader.SpecificationLoader.validateAndAssert(SpecificationLoader.java:252)
        at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactoryBuilder$1.run(IsisSessionFactoryBuilder.java:206)
        at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactory$1.call(IsisSessionFactory.java:322)
        at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactory$1.call(IsisSessionFactory.java:319)
        at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactory.doInSession(IsisSessionFactory.java:353)
        at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactory.doInSession(IsisSessionFactory.java:319)
        at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactory.doInSession(IsisSessionFactory.java:306)
        at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.system.session.IsisSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(IsisSessionFactoryBuilder.java:201)
        at org.apache.isis.tool.mavenplugin.IsisMojoAbstract.execute(IsisMojoAbstract.java:65)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    [DEBUG] flushTransaction
    [DEBUG] ... calling @PreDestroy method: org.apache.isis.objectstore.jdo.datanucleus.service.support.TimestampService: close
```

Here is the Provider entity

```
    package domainapp.modules.provider.dom;

    //import domainapp.modules.provider.ProviderModule;
    import domainapp.modules.provider.ProviderModule.PropertyDomainEvent;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.VersionStrategy;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Auditing;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.CommandReification;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.DomainObject;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Editing;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Parameter;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Property;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Publishing;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.SemanticsOf;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Title;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.i18n.TranslatableString;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.message.MessageService;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.title.TitleService;
import org.apache.isis.applib.util.ObjectContracts;
import org.apache.isis.schema.utils.jaxbadapters.PersistentEntityAdapter;
import domainapp.modules.provider.dom.ProviderRepository;
//

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.VersionStrategy;
import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import com.google.common.base.Objects;
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

import org.apache.isis.applib.Identifier;
import org.apache.isis.applib.NonRecoverableException;
import org.apache.isis.applib.RecoverableException;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Collection;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.DomainObject;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Editing;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.InvokeOn;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.InvokedOn;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.MemberOrder;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Optionality;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Parameter;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Programmatic;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Property;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Publishing;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.RestrictTo;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.SemanticsOf;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Where;
import org.apache.isis.applib.security.UserMemento;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.actinvoc.ActionInvocationContext;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.eventbus.EventBusService;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.eventbus.ObjectCreatedEvent;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.eventbus.ObjectLoadedEvent;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.eventbus.ObjectPersistedEvent;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.eventbus.ObjectPersistingEvent;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.eventbus.ObjectRemovingEvent;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.eventbus.ObjectUpdatedEvent;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.eventbus.ObjectUpdatingEvent;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.i18n.TranslatableString;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.message.MessageService;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.scratchpad.Scratchpad;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.title.TitleService;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.user.UserService;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.wrapper.HiddenException;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.wrapper.WrapperFactory;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.xactn.TransactionService;
import org.apache.isis.applib.util.ObjectContracts;
import org.apache.isis.applib.util.TitleBuffer;
import org.apache.isis.applib.value.Blob;
import org.apache.isis.applib.value.Clob;
import org.apache.isis.schema.utils.jaxbadapters.PersistentEntityAdapter;
//

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.MemberOrder;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Optionality;
//import org.apache.isis.applib.services.eventbus.PropertyDomainEvent;
import org.apache.isis.applib.value.Blob;
import org.isisaddons.wicket.fullcalendar2.cpt.applib.CalendarEvent;
import org.isisaddons.wicket.fullcalendar2.cpt.applib.CalendarEventable;
import org.isisaddons.wicket.gmap3.cpt.applib.Locatable;
import org.isisaddons.wicket.gmap3.cpt.applib.Location;
import org.isisaddons.wicket.gmap3.cpt.service.LocationLookupService;
import domainapp.modules.provider.dom.ProviderMenu;
import domainapp.modules.provider.dom.ProviderRepository;

@javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable(
        identityType = IdentityType.DATASTORE,
        schema = "simple"
)
@javax.jdo.annotations.DatastoreIdentity(
        strategy = javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY,
        column = "id")
@javax.jdo.annotations.Version(
        strategy = VersionStrategy.DATE_TIME,
        column = "version")
@javax.jdo.annotations.Queries({
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Query(
            name = "findByName",
            value = "SELECT "
            + "FROM domainapp.modules.provider.dom.Provider  "
            + "WHERE name.indexOf(:name) >= 0 ")
})
@javax.jdo.annotations.Unique(name = "Provider_name_UNQ", members = {"name"})
@DomainObject(
        autoCompleteRepository = ProviderRepository.class, // for drop-downs, unless autoCompleteNXxx() or choicesNXxx() present
        autoCompleteAction = "autoComplete",
 //       updatedLifecycleEvent = ToDoItem.UpdatedEvent.class,
        auditing = Auditing.ENABLED
)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PersistentEntityAdapter.class)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"name"})
@ToString(of = {"name"})
public class Provider implements Comparable<Provider>, Locatable {

    /**
     *
     * The fields of the Provider entity name String required, website String,
     * twitter String, facebook String, email String, primaryLocation String,
     * country String, city String, state String, street String, apiKey String,
     * apiUser String, endpointUrl String, logo ImageBlob
     */
    @Builder
    public Provider(final String name) {
        setName(name);
    }

    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "false", length = 40)
    @Title(prepend = "Provider: ")
    @Property(editing = Editing.DISABLED)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String name;
//parent
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "true")
    @Property(
            editing = Editing.ENABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Provider parent;    
//notes
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "true", length = 4000)
    @Property(
            editing = Editing.ENABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String notes;

//website
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "true", length = 40)
    @Property(
            editing = Editing.ENABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String website;
//facebook
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "true", length = 40)
    @Property(
            editing = Editing.ENABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String facebook;
//twitter
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "true", length = 40)
    @Property(
            editing = Editing.ENABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String twitter;
//instagram
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "true", length = 40)
    @Property(
            editing = Editing.ENABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String instagram;
//email String,
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "true", length = 40)
    @Property(
            editing = Editing.ENABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String email;
//  primaryLocation String, copy the way the location is done in todoApp, meaning we include 
//         locatable

    // public static class LocationDomainEvent extends ProviderModule.PropertyDomainEvent<Location> { }
    private Double locationLatitude;
    private Double locationLongitude;

    @Property(
            //ISIS-1138: Location value type not parsed from string, so fails to locate constructor
            //domainEvent = LocationDomainEvent.class,
            optionality = Optionality.OPTIONAL,
            //editing = Editing.ENABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    public Location getLocation() {
        return locationLatitude != null && locationLongitude != null ? new Location(locationLatitude, locationLongitude) : null;
    }

    public void setLocation(final Location location) {
        locationLongitude = location != null ? location.getLongitude() : null;
        locationLatitude = location != null ? location.getLatitude() : null;
    }

    @MemberOrder(name = "location", sequence = "1")
    public Provider updateLocation(
            final String address) {
        final Location location = this.locationLookupService.lookup(address);
        setLocation(location);
        setAddress(address);
        return this;
    }

//  address String,
    @MemberOrder(name = "location", sequence = "2")
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "true", length = 200)
    @Property(
            editing = Editing.DISABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String address;
//  city String,
//  state String,
//    street String,
//  apiKey String,
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "true", length = 40)
    @Property(
            editing = Editing.ENABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String apiKey;
//  apiUser String,
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "true", length = 40)
    @Property(
            editing = Editing.ENABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String apiUser;
//  endpointUrl String,
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(allowsNull = "true", length = 40)
    @Property(
            editing = Editing.ENABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String endpointUrl;
//  logo ImageBlob  

    //     public static class LogoDomainEvent extends PropertyDomainEvent<Blob>  { }
    @javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "false", columns = {
        @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(name = "logo_name")
        ,
            @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(name = "logo_mimetype")
        ,
            @javax.jdo.annotations.Column(name = "logo_bytes", jdbcType = "BLOB", sqlType = "LONGVARBINARY")
    })
    @Property(
            //           domainEvent = LogoDomainEvent.class,
            optionality = Optionality.OPTIONAL,
            editing = Editing.ENABLED,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Blob logo;
//
//updatename

    @Action(
            semantics = SemanticsOf.IDEMPOTENT,
            command = CommandReification.ENABLED,
            publishing = Publishing.ENABLED
    )
    public Provider updateName(
            @Parameter(maxLength = 40)
            final String name) {
        setName(name);
        return this;
    }

    public String default0UpdateName() {
        return getName();
    }

    public TranslatableString validate0UpdateName(final String name) {
        return name != null && name.contains("!") ? TranslatableString.tr("Exclamation mark is not allowed") : null;
    }

    @Action(semantics = SemanticsOf.NON_IDEMPOTENT_ARE_YOU_SURE)
    public void delete() {
        final String title = titleService.titleOf(this);
        messageService.informUser(String.format("'%s' deleted", title));
        repositoryService.remove(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Provider other) {
        return ObjectContracts.compare(this, other, "name");
    }

    @javax.inject.Inject
    RepositoryService repositoryService;

    @javax.inject.Inject
    TitleService titleService;

    @javax.inject.Inject
    MessageService messageService;

    @javax.inject.Inject
    private LocationLookupService locationLookupService;

    @javax.inject.Inject
    private ProviderMenu providerMenu;

    @javax.inject.Inject
    private ProviderRepository providerRepository;

}
```

And here is the ProviderRepository

```
    package domainapp.modules.provider.dom;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.DomainService;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.NatureOfService;
import org.apache.isis.applib.annotation.Programmatic;
import org.apache.isis.applib.query.QueryDefault;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.registry.ServiceRegistry2;
import org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService;

@DomainService(
        nature = NatureOfService.DOMAIN,
        repositoryFor = Provider.class
)
public class ProviderRepository {

    public List<Provider> listAll() {
        return repositoryService.allInstances(Provider.class);
    }

    public List<Provider> findByName(final String name) {
        return repositoryService.allMatches(
                new QueryDefault<>(
                        Provider.class,
                        "findByName",
                        "name", name));
    }

    public Provider create(final String name) {
        final Provider object = new Provider(name);
        serviceRegistry.injectServicesInto(object);
        repositoryService.persist(object);
        return object;
    }
    //region > autoComplete (programmatic)
    @Programmatic // doesn't need to be part of metamodel
    public List<Provider> autoComplete(final String description) {
        return findByName(description);
    }
    //endregion
    @javax.inject.Inject
    RepositoryService repositoryService;
    @javax.inject.Inject
    ServiceRegistry2 serviceRegistry;
    }
```

I have been unable to figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that you are running the Isis Maven plugin, and it is using an AppManifest (defined in the pom.xml) that - I am guessing - doesn't reference your new module that contains these classes.

I'm guessing you probably cloned the module-simple for your new module.  In that case you can fix things by either:

- adding in the new module to the [manifest referenced by the plugin](https://github.com/incodehq/incode-platform/blob/1.15.1.1/ex/app/quickstart/module-simple/pom.xml#L15) in your new module (not that of module-simple)
- using -Dskip.isis-validate on the mvn command line
- remove the plugin by [removing the mavenmixin-isis-validate](https://github.com/incodehq/incode-platform/blob/1.15.1.1/ex/app/quickstart/module-simple/pom.xml#L88)

HTH
Dan